# How to cast HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, typescript

i was wondering how it could be possible to substitute my own class instead of HttpErrorResponse like follow.

```
onSendFormDataClicked(event){
    this.http.post(url, body).catch((response:MyErrorClass)=>{
        console.log(response.GetErrorMessage());
    });
}

export class MyErrorClass extends HttpErrorResponse{
    public GetErrorMessage(){
        return "My Custom logic for error handling";
    }
}
```

I tried this but am getting GetErrorMessage() is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to change the response parameter in the `this.http.post` catch handler to be of type `MyErrorClass`. However you won't be able to do this without overriding the `this.http.post` method itself, which I doubt is what you want to do.

Instead you can implement your custom error handling within the catch block:

```
onSendFormDataClicked(event) {
  this.http.post(url, body).catch((response) => {
    const error = new MyErrorClass(response);
    console.log(error.getErrorMessage());
  });
}

export class MyErrorClass {
  constructor(response: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // Your logic here.
  }

  getErrorMessage() {
    return "My Custom logic for error handling";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was my other option, prolly what i will end up doing. Thanks.